# CSS for tr works with jsfiddle, doesn't work in html file, td and table do work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to format a table. In both Chrome and Firefox the style for the TR seems to be ignored when I load the file into the browser. I'm just trying to add a border to the row. The style for the table and the TD are used.

If I use the source in a fiddle it works.

for what it's worth extracting the style to a separate css file didn't help.

here's the link to the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kdubs/6Ppf4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css">

table
{
border: 5px solid red;
}

tr
{
border: 3px solid green;
}

td
{
border: 1px solid blue;
}

</style>

<body>

<div>
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>
one
</td>
<td>
two
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
three
</td>
<td>
four
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
five
</td>
<td>
six
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in the JSFiddle without normalization it doesn't work either - [Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ppf4/1/)

To fix it add `border-collapse: collapse;` to your table - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ppf4/2/)

Comment: that works. thanks. do you know why ? I'm trying to learn how to apply the style rules.